# Why do I get a null reference error when using something.Equals(null) in C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I keep getting a null reference error when I am trying to check if something is null. I have a class called User and I initialize the variable indvUser like so

```
User indvUser = api.Users.SearchByExternalId(session.UserInfo.UserId.ToString())
                   .Users.FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I want to check if indvUser is null like this

```
if (indvUser.Equals(null))
{
    int a = 1;
}
```

But I get a null reference error when using `Equals(null)` which I don't understand. If it actually is null i.e. there is no value, shouldn't `Equals(null)` return true?

Comment: Why not use `if (indvUser == null)`??

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, but I was curious why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `indvUser` is `null`, and `indvUser.Equals` is an instance method on your `User` object (i.e., it requires an non-null instance of your object), .NET will throw the error you attempt to use it.

For something like this, you could use this:

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(indvUser, null)
```

Or simply:

```
indvUser == null
```

Since neither of these approaches actually attempt to access methods or properties on the `indvUser` object itself, you should be safe from `NullReferenceExceptions`

Comment: Object.equals already calls ReferenceEquals http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In line:

```
indvUser.Equals(null)
```

if `indvUser` **is** null, how `Equals` method could be called on it? It simply can be seen as:

```
null.Equals(null)
```

You should compare it as `indvUser == null` or `object.ReferenceEquals(indvUser, null)`

Comment: Good explanation as to WHY the `NullReferenceException` is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Object.Equals is a method which is not static.  In order to call the Equals method, you must have an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If `indUser == null` you'd be doing `null.Equals(null)` which would throw an exception.